# Install pip and numpy for pypy3 OS Debian

Tags: python, numpy, docker, debian, pypy

How can I install pypy3 numpy and pip for Debian OS? I'm using docker container if it matters.
TO install pip and numpy I'm using this:

```
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "python3-pip"]
```

and

```
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "python3-numpy"]
```

but what if I want to use pypy3?
`RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "pypy3-pip"]` doesn't work.

Comment: Try using the `-m` flag: https://www.scivision.dev/pypy3-easy-install/ ?

Comment: this command doesn't work on debian

Comment: oh, my bad.....